# Passing data from one component to another in React using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I've created a simple react component for a form with few input fields using formik. My form is rendered three times on my home page for three different type of users, but I only have one button that is outside the component and on click it should save the data inside the `PersonalInformation` component. This is how my code looks inside my App.js (ignore the **users** and **data** for now):

```
{users.map((data, i) => { return <PersonalInformation key={i} /> })}
<Button>Submit</Button> //this is the button that needs to save the data inside of PersonalInfo component od click
```

My question is how I can save the data inside the three forms on click on the button? In end-point on the back end I would like to get an array of three objects, each objects will contain info about each field in the form. I guess what I need is to pass data from `PersonalInformation` component to `onClick()`event in `Button`, but I am not sure how to do that with formik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't use any state management, context etc i think simplest way is you can pass reference to your save method upper.

```js
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import PersonalInformation from "./PersonalInformation";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const saveRef = useRef(null)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PersonalInformation passSave={(ref) => saveRef.current = ref}/>
      <button onClick={() => saveRef.current()}> save </button>
    </div>
  );
}

//---------------------------------------------------------

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const PersonalInformation = ({passSave}) => {
    const formInput = useRef(null);
    const save = useCallback(() => {
      console.log(formInput.current.value)
    }, [formInput])

    useEffect(()=>{
      passSave(save)
    }, [passSave, save])

    return (
      <input type="text" ref={formInput} />
    )
}

export default PersonalInformation;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer, but I don't understand how save is implemented here? With this approach how will I get an array of objects in the back end ?(my component PersonalInformation is shown three times in my home page, so I will have three objects with type personalInfo that contain information about each field in the component, so I would need array of three objects in the back end).

Comment: you have to call to you backend api from save method. make fetch request from this method and pass the data. (preper some helper function, object or just put code direct in component).

Comment: And how would it be if I use react context?

Comment: if you have just one action from button then it will be over engineering... but. : Pernoalnfo will be looked alomost the same, just passSave will be from use context.however button comopnen need to be wrapped in Button component in witch you will consume context and call function stored therein by PersonalInfo.

Comment: The solution with useRef() is working, but with small problem. I implemented it a little bit differently. I am using an array for the refs of the children in the parent component.  but I have a problem with having a lot more ref that I should have. Because my component is shown three times I need 3 refs, but instead I have 85, the first three are filled correctly, than I get three refs of nulls and after that the first three values are repeated, and this is repeating.  Do you have idea why is  this happening?

Comment: Probably you add push new refs to array on each render. can you reproduce this on sandbox ?

Comment: you can store on useRef({ref 1: fun, ref 2: fun , ref 3: fun}) object with references then you don't push more and more new refs if you use always the same key for given children object.

Comment: [code sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/) pls use this. put your code, event if its not work ... in comment it will be really hard to understand problem

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-swartz-s2rpn?file=/src/App.js) --- can you open the link? it has errors, it is just for demonstration

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-panini-q8fdh?file=/src/App.js) don't push to array use object and id  or use Map(dictionary) to store your refs. then you can call expected... if you store them in array it is not stable to rely of array order

Comment: @Ajifos if you go to my link then we can speek on the sandbox chat.

Comment: I don't have account. Than you for your help. I will try to change it to Map or first approach.